# js library - generate pdf from json

Tags: library, javascript, pdf-viewer

I'm looking for js library for generating pdf from json Emphasis on performance.

**Requirement**

1. Support IE11,Edge,Chrome Preview and download.
2. Performance: Ability to render 5000 rows in up to 5 seconds
3. Ease of design (graphic)
4. Configurable using JSON for the report parameters

5, Known company + supoprt

6. Widely spread: adopted by the developers community

   I tried [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) and I was disappointed with performance issues and the lack of IE support.